# Using CASL v6 with NestJs

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, casl

Following the example on NestJs's CASL implementation, how would you implement same in casl v6 as `Ability` is now deprecated by casl.

Here's how far I've gone:

### 2nd Implementation

```
import { User } from 'src/user/entities/user.entity';
import {
  Ability,
  AbilityBuilder,
  AbilityClass,
  ExtractSubjectType,
  InferSubjects,
  PureAbility,
} from '@casl/ability';
import { Permissions } from 'src/shared';

type Subjects = InferSubjects<typeof User> | 'all';

export type AppAbility = Ability<[Permissions, Subjects]>;

@Injectable()
export class CaslAbilityFactory {
  defineAbilityFor(user: User) {
    const { can, cannot, build } = new AbilityBuilder<AppAbility>();

    if (user.isSuperAdmin) {
      can(Permissions.Manage, 'all'); // read-write access to everything
    } else {
      can(Permissions.Read, 'all'); // read-only access to everything
    }

    can(Permissions.Update, User, { id: user.id });
    cannot(Permissions.Delete, User, { isPublished: true });

    return build({
      // Read https://casl.js.org/v5/en/guide/subject-type-detection#use-classes-as-subject-types for details
      detectSubjectType: (item) =>
        item.constructor as ExtractSubjectType<Subjects>,
    });
  }
}
```

### 1st Implementation

```
@Injectable()
export class CaslAbilityFactory {
  createForUser(user: User) {
    const { can, cannot, build } = new AbilityBuilder<
      Ability<[Permissions, Subjects]>
    >(Ability as AbilityClass<AppAbility>);

    if (user.isSuperAdmin) {
      can(Permissions.Manage, 'all'); // read-write access to everything
    } else {
      can(Permissions.Read, 'all'); // read-only access to everything
    }

    // can(Permissions.Update, Article, { authorId: user.id });
    // cannot(Permissions.Delete, Article, { isPublished: true });

    return build({
      // Read https://casl.js.org/v5/en/guide/subject-type-detection#use-classes-as-subject-types for details
      detectSubjectType: (item) =>
        item.constructor as ExtractSubjectType<Subjects>,
    });
  }
}
```

#### Results

The 1st implementation throws no errors, but warns about deprecation while instantiating the ability.
[image: casl-implementation-1]

The 2nd implementation throws an error because AbilityBuilder expects
[image: casl-implementation-2]

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

Replace `Ability` with `createMongoAbility` while instantiating `AbilityBuilder`.

#### Reason

This is required because, despite the name, `Ability` is not the abstract factory for building abilities in Casl. That class is called `PureAbility`, and `Ability` extends it to include MongoQuery options (so that you can limit `can` or `cannot` conditions with queries, like `{ isPublished: true }`).

This confusing nomenclature is the reason for the deprecation. In the future `PureAbility` will be renamed to just `Ability`, and any extension of the class will be handled either manually or by using other factories to create it, like the already available `createMongoAbility`.

You can call it directly:

```
const ability = createMongoAbility<[Action, Subject]>();
```

Or pass it to AbilityBuilder, since it expects a factory:

```
const { can, cannot, build } = new AbilityBuilder(createMongoAbility);
```

#### Example

To implement the example from the NestJS docs using CASL >= 6

> **casl-ability.factory.ts**

```
import { AbilityBuilder, createMongoAbility, ExtractSubjectType, InferSubjects, MongoQuery } from "@casl/ability";
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";

export enum Action {
  Manage = 'manage',
  Create = 'create',
  Read = 'read',
  Update = 'update',
  Delete = 'delete',
}

type Subjects = InferSubjects<typeof Article | typeof User> | 'all';
type PossibleAbilities = [Action, Subjects];
type Conditions = MongoQuery;

export type AppAbility = MongoAbility<PossibleAbilities, Conditions>;

@Injectable()
export class CaslAbilityFactory {
  createForUser(user: User) {
    const { can, cannot, build } = new AbilityBuilder(createMongoAbility<PossibleAbilities, Conditions>);

    // Users
    can([Action.Read, Action.Update], User, { _id: user._id });
    can(Action.Read, Article, { authorId: user._id })

    // Admins
    if (user.isAdmin) {
      can(Action.Manage, 'all');
    }

    return build({
      // Read https://casl.js.org/v5/en/guide/subject-type-detection#use-classes-as-subject-types for details
      detectSubjectType: (item) =>
        item.constructor as ExtractSubjectType<Subjects>,
    });
  }
}
```